# Use rownum to indicate what rows I have pulled back

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have table of people, with firstname and lastname.

| firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- |
| a | a |
| b | b |
| c | c |
| d | d |
| e | e |
| f | f |
| g | g |
| h | h |
| i | i |
| j | j |

I want to query from a specific point. For example.

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME WHERE FIRSTNAME > 'e' order by firstname, lastname
```

Great.  But what I would really like is for the result to tell me that result is actually from the 6th row.  I have tried

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROW_NUMBER(OVER ORDER BY lastname) WHERE FIRSTNAME > 'e' order by firstname, lastname
```

But in that case, row_number will start from 1 when I want it to tell me that is actually the 6th element from the query

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME order by firstname, lastname
```

I want to do that without actually retrieving the first five rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to enumerate the rows, then filter in the outer query:

```
select *
from (
    select firstname, lastname, row_number() over(order by firstname, lastname) as rn
    from mytable
) t
where firstname > 'e' 
order by firstname, lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, seqnum
FROM (SELECT e.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY firstname) as seqnum
      FROM e
     ) e
WHERE FIRSTNAME > 'e'
ORDER BY firstname, lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` clause at the end of your SQL to tell Oracle which row(s) you want.

In your case, you want the 6th row, so it would be:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname 
FROM mytable
ORDER BY firstname, lastname
-- Skip the first 5 rows and get me the next one (i.e., the 6th one)
OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Execution-wise, this basically does the same thing as the other answers that have been posted.  It's just makes the developer's intention a little more explicit, imo.